# SQL Server - SELECT statement returning null

Tags: mysql, sql, select

The following SELECT statement results this

```
SELECT ProductID, SUM(Quantity) AS Quantity
FROM Production.ProductInventory
WHERE ProductID NOT IN (1001)
GROUP BY ProductID;
```

[image]

How come the edited SELECT statement below does not produce anything?

```
SELECT ProductID, SUM(Quantity) AS Quantity
FROM Production.ProductInventory
WHERE Quantity >= 1800
GROUP BY ProductID;
```

[image]

Comment: Are you serious?  None of the *sums* that you have shown exceed 1800.  If the value is always non-negative, then I wouldn't expect such large values.

Comment: @GordonLinoff There are sums larger than 1800 just can't see in the image as the list goes down a lot

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You added `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT ProductID, SUM(Quantity) AS Quantity
FROM Production.ProductInventory
WHERE Quantity >= 1800  -- no single row with Quantity that is higher than 1800
GROUP BY ProductID;
```

You probably want to filter values after aggregation:

```
SELECT ProductID, SUM(Quantity) AS Quantity
FROM Production.ProductInventory
GROUP BY ProductID
HAVING SUM(Quantity) >= 1800;   -- HAVING instead of WHERE
```

Filtering:

- WHERE - before aggregation
- HAVING - after aggregation

Answer (score 0):

The `WHERE` is *before* aggregation, so it filters out all rows (apparently).  You want `HAVING`.  But, fix the aliases, so they are not confusing:

```
SELECT ProductID, SUM(Quantity) AS total_Quantity
FROM Production.ProductInventory
GROUP BY ProductID
HAVING total_Quantity >= 1800;
```

Or, repeat the expression:

```
SELECT ProductID, SUM(Quantity) AS total_Quantity
FROM Production.ProductInventory
GROUP BY ProductID
HAVING SUM(Quantity) >= 1800;
```

Comment: @RyanWilson . . . As a point in fact, Lucasz had not (from what I could tell) adding the `having` portion of his answer when I first answered this.  It is trickier to find edit histories for the first five minutes, but his answer continued to use `WHERE`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff If I missed that, then I apologize. I remove my down vote. Well, I tried to remove my down vote. No luck. I'll see if a moderator can help.